# Fashion related content queries (DBpedia or Freebase)

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, freebase, dbpedia

I'm trying to figure out how to make some queries through which I should get fashion related content, like an list of known cloth types, or cloth manufactures, or well known fashion designers. 
I have spent the last few days trying to figure out to make such an query through DBpedia or Freebase, but I couldn't seem to figure it out. Examples that kinda match what I need I couldn't find...

Can someone help me with this, some short example on which I can start to work on or some tutorials that explain how can I achieve something like this?

Thank you

---

**Later Edit**

---

I have also found that DBpedia contains an ontology property "dressCode" and I've found these pages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dress_code_(Western) and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dress_code which lists some basic dress codes, like "Formal", "Casual"... 
Now my idea is to get properties from each one of these sub-categories (or what they are defined as on DBpedia, as I see they differ from one other). 
Any suggestion on how to do this ?

---

**Later Edit**

---

I have managed to make some queries to display some information that could actually help me:

[SPARQL - list of social events](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%28%3Flabel+as+%3Fsub%29+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%7B+%0D%0A++++%3Fsub+skos%3Abroader+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3ASocial_events%3E+.+%0D%0A++++%3Fsub+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel.+%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B%3Fsubsub+dcterms%3Asubject+%3Fsub%7D+%0D%0A++%7D++%0D%0A%7D+%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

`SELECT DISTINCT (?label as ?sub) 
WHERE { 
  { 
    ?sub skos:broader <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Social_events> . 
    ?sub rdfs:label ?label. 
    OPTIONAL {?subsub dcterms:subject ?sub} 
  }

}`

[SPARQL - list of dress codes](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%28%3Flabel+as+%3FdressCode%29+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%7B+%0D%0A++++%3FdressCode+dcterms%3Asubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3ADress_codes%3E+.+%0D%0A++++%3FdressCode+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel.+%0D%0Afilter%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%22EN%22%29%29+%0D%0A++%7D++%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

`SELECT DISTINCT (?label as ?dressCode) 
WHERE { 
  { 
    ?dressCode dcterms:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Dress_codes> . 
    ?dressCode rdfs:label ?label. 
filter(langMatches(lang(?label),"EN")) 
  }

}`

Now I would like to retrieve the "subject of" for each dress code so that I can connect somehow the dress codes to the social events, but I'm having issues to do that.

---

**Later Edit**

---

I got to the conclusion that I can't find an ontology that actually matches my needs. Basically I need to get cloth properties based on event types so I can make cloth recommendations. Except the restrictions from the event types I also want to add other properties like the current fashion trend, the season in which the event will take place, geo-location (if possible), and other small details like these.
Now I'm trying to use existing ontologies and data that exists on DBpedia & Freebase, like: 'Dress code', 'Event type', 'Colors', 'Fashion designer', 'Fabric', 'Texture', 'Manufacturer', 'Size' and combine them into an ontology which I can actually use in my project to actually make cloth recommendations.

Can anyone help me with some guidelines on how I can do this ? I tried to use Protege to combine some ontologies and extend them after that, but finally I failed to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be one of the first places you can start with is the [DBpedia ontology](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php). When I search for keywords like Fashion, I can see that there are classes like FashionDesigner. So I can check about about the information about fashion designers in DPpedia with a simple SPARQL query like the following using the DPpedia public SPARQL endpoint.

(a) [a list of fashion designers](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3FfashionDesigner%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3FfashionDesigner%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFashionDesigner%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on):

```
select distinct ?fashionDesigner 
where {
 ?fashionDesigner a dbpedia-owl:FashionDesigner
} 
LIMIT 100
```

(b) [what are the information generally available about a fashion designer](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20select%20distinct%20%3Fproperty%0D%0A%20%20%20%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3FfashionDesigner%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFashionDesigner%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
select distinct ?property
where {
 ?fashionDesigner a dbpedia-owl:FashionDesigner;
                  ?property ?value .

}
```

I can also select one of the results of query (a) such as [Donna Karan](http://dbpedia.org/page/Donna_Karan) take a look what kind of information she has.

So now, my task is to see who the well-known fashion designers. I don't know much about fashion but I see some of them have awards. So I can query for the fashion designers who have won awards.

(c) [Fashion designers who have won awards](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20distinct%20%3FfashionDesigner%20%3Faward%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FfashionDesigner%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFashionDesigner%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3Aawards%20%3Faward%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
   select distinct ?fashionDesigner ?award
    where {
     ?fashionDesigner a dbpedia-owl:FashionDesigner;
             dbpprop:awards ?award .
    }
```

I was only using very basic SPARQL queries but you can use more complex queries when you get to know more about the fashion related concepts and properties in the data.

You can follow a similar approach for classes such as [LineOfFashion](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/LineOfFashion), [Clothing](http://dbpedia.org/page/Clothing), etc.

For example
(d) [a list of clothing manufactures](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20select%20distinct%20%3Fcompany%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20dbpedia-owl%3Aproduct%09dbpedia%3AClothing%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dcterms%3Asubject%20category%3AClothing_brands%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

select distinct ?company where {
?company dbpedia-owl:product    dbpedia:Clothing;
         dcterms:subject category:Clothing_brands .
} LIMIT 100

The more you explore, you can build better queries. I hope this will help you to get started.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nandana, this was exactly what I was missing. I will accept your answer as it got me in the right direction and it also has some examples that are really useful for what I need.

Comment: do you have an idea how could I also get an list of cloth types ? I can't seem to find an ontology based on that. 
Also, if you have some suggestion on how I could get some fashion trends, from DBpedia or any other service, I would gladly appreciate it.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know a famous cloth type to start with? If there is a way to find one instance of cloth type, you can start from there and explore more.

Comment: At some point I found Jeans (http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Jeans), but I don't know if this is the correct way to go with. What I could figure out is that they are from the type Textile (http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Textile).
Also, another thing that I'm trying to figure out is if DBpedia or Freebase have some Fashion Trends information, like for example, what kind of clothes should be worn this fall/winter.

Comment: I have also found that dbpedia contains an ontology property "dressCode" and I've found this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dress_code_(Western) or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dress_code  which lists some basic dress codes, like "Formal", "Casual"... Now my ideea is to get properties from each one of these sub-categories (or what they are defined as on DBpedia, as I see the differ from one other). Do you have any suggestion on how to do this ? 
PS: I'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that returns award winning fashion designers from Freebase:  https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?limit=10&scoring=entity&filter=(all+type%3A%2Faward%2Faward_winner+notable%3A%22fashion+designer%22)&lang=en&indent=true

There's a little on-line utility that you can use to experiment with this and check out some of the other items that you were interested in: 
http://freebase-search.freebaseapps.com/?filter=(all+type%3A%2Faward%2Faward_winner+notable%3A%22fashion+designer%22)&limit=10&scoring=entity&lang=en

Comment: Thank you @Tom Morris, this query does not really help me much, but at least through the on-line utility you provided I will look for more info on Freebase.
Anyway, I'll update my question as I think I must approach a new way for getting to the expected result.